# Django: Track specific user actions

Tags: django, user-tracking

How can I track specific user actions with Django.

For example:

- user logged in
- user changes password
- user visited a specific page
- rest api call within a specific view took 300ms
- user deleted / updated / created a specific model

Is there a nice third party app which can do this for me and display this information in an human readable admin interface or at least in django-admin?

If there is no app out there. How would you do this with Django?

Comment: https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream this might be helpful

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting but not exactly what I want. I think I could use it and write for some edge cases my own code.

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843663/7109869) on this OP's other question [Django: How to create a user action log/trace with vizualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775800/django-how-to-create-a-user-action-log-trace-with-vizualization) seems to be what OP is looking for.